# Finding remainder of two number without modulus

Tags: javascript

Instructions: Write a function called "modulo". Given 2 numbers, "modulo" returns the remainder after dividing num1 by num2.

This is my code so far. When I run it on repl.it it gives the correct remainder, but when I submit the program it goes into an infinite loop and I have no clue why. I figure the return functions in the for loop would just automatically exit it. Any help would be appreciated, thanks. Basically I'm adding number2 constantly until it either hits number 1 or goes higher than it. If it goes higher, I subtract number 2 once, and find the difference.

```
function modulo(num1, num2) {
    if(num1 === 0) {
      return 0;
    }
    if(num2 === 0) {
      return NaN;
    }
    if(isNaN(num1) === true || isNaN(num2) === true) {
      return NaN;
    }

    var i = 0;

    for( i = 0; i <= num1;) {
      i += num2;
      if(i === num1) {
        return 0;
      }
      else if(i > num1) {
        i = i - num2;
        console.log(i, num1);
        return num1 - i;
      }
   }
}

var output = modulo(25, 4);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "submit the program"?

Comment: Sorry I'm on a javascript preparation website that uses repl.it. Submit uses numerous tests that make sure your program is working correctly. So it'll test negative numbers, and 0's, and NaN's to make sure the modulus is correct.

Comment: What website is it, if you don't mind me asking? That's strange, because I'm calling the function just fine in my console. Also, see my answer below for some quick tips on how to clean up the code. :)

Comment: Looks like it is working for me (for positive numbers) -- what is your exact problem?  Why do you think you have an infinite loop?

Answer (score 1):

```
function modulo(num1, num2) { var div = num1/num2;
var remainder = div - Math.floor(div); // gives the decimal point value left out from the division
return Math.round(remainder * num2); // multiplies the remainder with num2 and gives a whole number value
}
```

This is pretty simpler and should work all times

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure where the infinite loop is showing up; I've plugged your code into console and I can call the function just fine. What site are you using to validate?

Also, without altering too much of your exercise, I'd like to point out a couple of tiny areas where you can consolidate your code to improve readability:

```
    if(num2 === 0) {
      return NaN;
    }

    if(isNaN(num1) === true || isNaN(num2) === true) {
      return NaN;
    }
```

can be distilled down into

```
    if (num2 === 0 || isNaN(num1) || isNaN(num2)) {
      return NaN;
    }
```

because in JavaScript, booleans work in such a way that everything with a real value is considered to be true, i.e. `isNaN(num1)` and `isNaN(num2)` are "true" by default.

Also, remember that you can use all your assignment operators; it's completely optional, but since you used one (`i += num2;`), I figured I'd point out that you could use another further down the code (`i -= num2;`).

Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

It could be another option:

```js
function modulo(num1, num2) {

    if(isNaN(num1) || isNaN(num2) ) {
      return NaN;
    }

    var strResult = (num1/num2).toString();
    
    var decimalPart =
      parseFloat(strResult.substr(strResult.indexOf(".")));
     
    var remainder = Math.round(decimalPart*num2);
    return remainder;
}

console.log(modulo(77,9), (77%9)); // 5
console.log(modulo(549,123), (549%123)); // 57
console.log(modulo(33,6), (33%6)); // 3
```

Comment: A completely different implementation doesn't explain why the OP might be having trouble with their own version.

Comment: After checking, the modulus is simply `num - mod * Math.floor(num / mod)`. But I don't think that helps the OP.